# Entity Framework include vs where

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

My database structure is this: an `OptiUser` belongs to multiple `UserGroup`s through the `IdentityMap` table, which is a matching table (many to many) with some additional properties attached to it. Each `UserGroup` has multiple `OptiDashboard`s.

I have a GUID string which identifies a particular user (`wlid` in this code). I want to get an `IEnumerable` of all of the `OptiDashboards` for the user identified by `wlid`.

Which of these two Linq-to-Entities queries is the most efficient? Do they run the same way on the back-end?

Also, can I shorten option 2's `Include` statements to just `.Include("IdentityMaps.UserGroup.OptiDashboards")`?

```
using (OptiEntities db = new OptiEntities())
{
    // option 1
    IEnumerable<OptiDashboard> dashboards = db.OptiDashboards
        .Where(d => d.UserGroups
            .Any(u => u.IdentityMaps
                .Any(i => i.OptiUser.WinLiveIDToken == wlid)));

    // option 2
    OptiUser user = db.OptiUsers
        .Include("IdentityMaps")
        .Include("IdentityMaps.UserGroup")
        .Include("IdentityMaps.UserGroup.OptiDashboards")
        .Where(r => r.WinLiveIDToken == wlid).FirstOrDefault();

    // then I would get the dashboards through user.IdentityMaps.UserGroup.OptiDashboards
    // (through foreach loops...)
}
```

Comment: You said "Linq to SQL", did you mean "Linq to Entites" since you tagged this with the entity-framework?

Comment: I guess. I mean whatever the .Where's and .Include's fall under.. not exactly sure if that's LINQ to SQL or Entities.

Comment: @NickB: **Linq-to-SQL** is one data-access technology - it uses DBML files for its model. **Entity Framework** (and its accompanying Linq-to-Entities) is another technology - uses EDMX model files (or a code-first) approach. Those two are vastly different - you need to know which one you're using before we can help you!

Comment: @marc_s Ah, thanks for the explanation! I'm using Linq-to-Entities with EDMX model files.

Comment: @NickB: I had already updated your question accordingly (everything was hinting at Entity Framework and thus Linq-to-Entities....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding what the `Include` function actually does.  Option 1 is purely a query syntax which has no effect on what is returned by the entity framework. Option 2, with the `Include` function instructs the entity framework to *Eagerly Fetch* the related rows from the database when returns the results of the query.

So option 1 will result in some joins, but the "select" part of the query will be restricted to the `OptiDashboards` table.

Option 2 will result in joins as well, but in this case it will be returning the results from **all** the included tables, which obviously is going to introduce more of a performance hit.  But at the same time, the results will include all the related entities you need, avoiding the [possible] need for more round-trips to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Include` will render as `joins` an you will the able to access the data from those tables in you user object (Eager Loading the properties).

The `Any` query will render as `exists` and not load the user object with info from the other tables.

For best performance if you don't need the additional info use the `Any` query

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, the first option would almost certainly perform better, simply because it would be retrieving less information. Besides that, I wanted to point out that you could also write the query this way:

```
var dashboards =
    from u in db.OptiUsers where u.WinLiveIDToken == wlid
    from im in u.IdentityMaps
    from d in im.UserGroup.OptiDashboards
    select d;
```

I would expect the above to perform similarly to the first option, but you may (or may not) prefer the above form.